# How to get the name of a function alias in a D template?

Tags: templates, d, introspection

I have a function template that accepts a function as an argument. I'd like to be able to get the name of the function argument from within the template. A complete example is below. See the line marked "COMPILE ERROR" -- I've tried to do a variety of things similar to this but I keep getting the same error, "function throws.thrower (int n) is not callable".

```
import std.array;
import std.conv;
import std.format;
import std.stdio;

int thrower(int n)
{
    if(n > 5)
        throw new core.exception.RangeError("too big");
    return n * 2;
}

int thrower2(int x, int y)
{
    int product = x * y;
    if(product > 25)
        throw new core.exception.RangeError("too big");
    return product;
}

void assertThrows(alias fun, E, T...)(T t)
{
    try
    {
        fun(t);

        auto writer = appender!string();
        formattedWrite(writer,
                       "Expected %s to throw %s, but it did not",
// throws.d(32): Error: function throws.thrower (int n) is not callable using argument types ()

                       //fun.stringof, // <<-- COMPILE ERROR
                       "?",
                       E.stringof);

        throw new core.exception.AssertError(writer.data);
    }
    catch(E ex)
    {
        // Success - we got the expected exception - do nothing.
    }
    // We don't catch any other exceptions -- if these occur they will
    // cause a failure directly, or be handled by other test code that
    // may be expecting the exception. Either way we don't want to
    // interfere.
}

int main()
{
    assert(thrower(5) == 10);
    assertThrows!(thrower, core.exception.RangeError)(6);
    assertThrows!(thrower2, core.exception.RangeError)(9, 9);
    assertThrows!(thrower2, core.exception.RangeError)(1, 1); // Should fail

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would point out that there's no guarantee that `fun` is even a function with a name. It could be lambda function or some other callable which got passed in. Also, we have `std.exception.assertThrown`, so there's already something in the standard library which does what your function is trying to do (though it uses the file and line number and not the function name in the error message).

Comment: Thanks for the tip - `fullyQualifiedName` gives "main.__funcliteral1" when I test it with a lambda, which seems reasonable enough. File and line is probably more helpful. I'm very new to D, so the pointer to `assertThrown` in the standard library is helpful. I was looking for it in the wrong places and didn't realize it was in that module. At least I learned a half dozen new things while reinventing this particular wheel :)

Comment: If you don't need fully qualified name and are sure it is a valid symbol, `__traits(identifier, Symbol)` will do the trick too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing I was looking for is [std.traits.fullyQualifiedName](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits.html#fullyQualifiedName); changing this line fixes the compile error and gives the desired output.

```
    formattedWrite(writer,
                   "Expected %s to throw %s, but it did not",
                   fullyQualifiedName!fun,
                   E.stringof);
```

This gives output for the program in the question:

```
core.exception.AssertError@throws.d(37): Expected throws.thrower2 to throw RangeError, but it did not
```

which is what I am looking for.